# Django simple syndication example gives: ImportError, cannot import name Feed

Tags: django, django-syndication

I'm trying to set up the [simple syndication example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/#a-simple-example) from the Django docs, in a working project. But I'm getting an ImportError, even though I'm sure I've copied the example exactly.

Here's what I have in feeds.py:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed 
class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    # etc
```

And here's what I have in urls.py:

```
from election.feeds import LatestEntriesFeed
#... further down, at the appropriate line...
    # RSS feed
    (r'^feed/$', LatestEntriesFeed()),
```

But Django says it can't import the Feed class from django.contrib.syndication.views:

```
ImportError at /feed/
cannot import name Feed
....feeds.py in <module>
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
```

Any ideas? I'm baffled!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is for the development version. Feeds have changed quite a lot in preparation for 1.2. If you're using 1.1, you should use [the 1.1 docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/syndication/).

Comment: That would be it... Thank you.